# Airbase-ng & Metasploit the perfect pair

Tags: wifi, metasploit

So if I am running an airbase-ng soft AP, I have several clients connecting to me. I can run metasploit against them once they are connected manually, but that is oh too much effort.

Is there anyway to automatically run metasploit against any connecting clients. I have looked into the autopwn module, however, this is deprecated.

Can anyone suggest a future proof automated method of metasploitin' connected clients. Something that I could theoretically leave alone once setup.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is [Karmetasploit](http://dev.metasploit.com/redmine/projects/framework/wiki/Karmetasploit). It is the integration of Karma with MSF to offer a variety of network services to wifi clients.

Several tutorials and videos are available.

In addition, there are hardware solutions, like the [wifi-pineapple](http://hakshop.myshopify.com/products/wifi-pineapple) from Hak9.